# How to resize all tmux panes at once to fit the screen size and display resolution?

Tags: tmux

I have created 4 panes in one window - as I flip between my 13" laptop to 27" monitor, the tmux panes's relative positions do not adjust themselves. How to resize them all at once?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For your `tmux.conf`, perhaps you're looking for something along the lines of:

```
set-hook -g client-resized resize-pane
```

Notes:

- `set-hook` "hooks" events to commands.
- `client-resized` occurs whenever the client is resized.
- `resize-pane` or `resizep` (same) resizes panes on the current window, assuming pane layout is proportional.